# VHDL No Function declaration for operator "-"

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

So i have a task to do the mod operation between 2 vectors(called here dividendo and divisor), so what i need is dividendo mod divisor.
We have some restrictions on this code, that is, we cant use iee_std_logic_1164, textio, etc. I think the only libraries allowed are IEEE and IEEE.numeric_bit

The algorithm to this operation tells me to:

```
while(dividendo >= divisor){
  dividendo = dividendo - divisor
 }
return dividendo
```

And then i wrote this vhdl file:

```
 library IEEE;

entity resto is
port (clock , reset : in bit ;
    inicio : in bit ;
    fim : out bit ;
    dividendo , divisor : in bit_vector (15 downto 0) ;
    resto : out bit_vector (15 downto 0)
) ;
end resto;

architecture processo of resto is
  signal dividendo_n : bit_vector (15 downto 0) := dividendo;
  signal divisor_n : bit_vector (15 downto 0) := divisor;
  begin

        process (clock, reset)
        begin
            if reset = '1' then
                fim <= '0';
                resto <= "0000000000000000";
            elsif clock'event and clock = '1' and inicio = '1'  then
              if divisor = "0000000000000000" then
                fim <= '1';
                resto <= dividendo;
              else
                while ( dividendo_n >= divisor_n) loop
                  dividendo_n <= dividendo_n - divisor_n;
                  end loop;,

                resto <= dividendo_n;
            end if;
            end if;
            end process;
end processo;
```

But i keep getting this error: **No Function declaration for operator "-" on line**

```
dividendo_n <= dividendo_n - divisor_n;
```

Any thoughts? I'm a beginner on this language so I  don't know much about what is really going on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to use ieee.numeric_bit, you should USE (hint) it. Then check out what functionality it provides (the sources are available on the Internet and also in your local installation of whatever toolset you use). And - since you are a beginner - it might be advisable to start at the beginning: read a good book about VHDL and learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use mathematical operations on numerical data types like integer, unsigned and signed in VHDL. The bit_vector type isn't a numerical type so you can't use the subtraction operation.

If you are limited to only using bit or bit_vector types then you will have to implement a binary subtractor circuit to perform this operation.