# VHDL "Non-shared variable declaration not allowed here"

Tags: vhdl, hdl, ghdl

I have this code that essentialy calculates the mod of 2 numbers

```
library IEEE;

use ieee.numeric_bit.all;

entity resto is
    port (clock , reset : in bit ;
        inicio : in bit ;
        fim : out bit ;
        dividendo , divisor : in bit_vector (15 downto 0) ;
        resto : out bit_vector (15 downto 0)
    ) ;
    end resto;

architecture processo of resto is
    variable    dividendovar : integer range 0 to  15;
    begin

    process(clock, reset) is
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            fim <= '0';
            resto <= "0000000000000000";
        elsif clock'event and clock = '1' and inicio = '1' then
            dividendovar <= to_integer(unsigned(dividendo));
                if (divisor = "0000000000000000") then
                    -- report "zero"; 
                    resto <= dividendo;
                    fim <= '1';
                elsif (dividendovar = to_integer(unsigned(divisor))) then
                    -- report "menor"; 
                    -- report "dividendoaux vale "& integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(dividendoaux))) ; 
                    resto <= "0000000000000000";
                    fim <= '1';
                elsif (to_integer(unsigned(dividendo)) < to_integer(unsigned(divisor))) then
                    resto <= dividendo;
                    fim <= '1';
                else -- comeca a subtrair
                    while (dividendovar > to_integer(unsigned(divisor))) loop
                        dividendovar := dividendovar - to_integer(unsigned(divisor));
                    end loop ;
                    resto <= bit_vector(to_unsigned(dividendovar, resto'length));
                    fim <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
            end process;
end architecture;
```

But on the line

```
variable    dividendovar : integer range 0 to  15;
```

I'm getting this error **"Non-shared variable declaration not allowed here"**.

Any clues of what i'm doing wrong or missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The entire error message includes a line number and character count pointing to the reserved word `variable`. A non-shared variable declaration can only occur as a subprogram parameter declaration, a subprogram declarative item or a process declarative item. Your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62383489/vhdl-no-function-declaration-for-operator) declared signal `dividendo_n` as a block declarative item. Simply changing the name and declaring it class `variable` isn't sufficient.

Comment: Did you intend that divendovar be only 4 bits (range 0 to 15)?   I am guessing that it is 16 bits.

Comment: Another thought, your while loop probably is not synthesizable.    Have you though of using a for loop and potentially iterating no more than N times where N is the number of bits in divisor?

Answer (score 1):

Variables should be declared inside a `process` and therefore have a restricted scope.

```
library IEEE;

use ieee.numeric_bit.all;

entity resto is
    port (clock , reset : in bit ;
        inicio : in bit ;
        fim : out bit ;
        dividendo , divisor : in bit_vector (15 downto 0) ;
        resto : out bit_vector (15 downto 0)
    ) ;
    end resto;

architecture processo of resto is
    begin

    process(clock, reset) is
    variable    dividendovar : integer range 0 to  15;
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            fim <= '0';
            resto <= "0000000000000000";
        elsif clock'event and clock = '1' and inicio = '1' then
            dividendovar <= to_integer(unsigned(dividendo));
                if (divisor = "0000000000000000") then
                    -- report "zero"; 
                    resto <= dividendo;
                    fim <= '1';
                elsif (dividendovar = to_integer(unsigned(divisor))) then
                    -- report "menor"; 
                    -- report "dividendoaux vale "& integer'image(to_integer(unsigned(dividendoaux))) ; 
                    resto <= "0000000000000000";
                    fim <= '1';
                elsif (to_integer(unsigned(dividendo)) < to_integer(unsigned(divisor))) then
                    resto <= dividendo;
                    fim <= '1';
                else -- comeca a subtrair
                    while (dividendovar > to_integer(unsigned(divisor))) loop
                        dividendovar := dividendovar - to_integer(unsigned(divisor));
                    end loop ;
                    resto <= bit_vector(to_unsigned(dividendovar, resto'length));
                    fim <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
            end process;
end architecture;
```

As mentioned in the comments, globally shared variables were available until VHDL2002 standard. If still needed they should be protected now I think. But so far I newer came across a use-case where a variable was needed.

I'd anyway prefer `signals` over `variables` in all my designs whenever possible.

Comment: Shared variables like this are only allowed in VHDL 1993. From VHDL 2002, shared variables must be a protected type (which are not currently synthesisable in any tools I know).

Comment: The OP is a newbie.   It would be best if you updated your example to show the variable declared in a process.    Like @Tricky said, shared variables of an ordinary type were deprecated and removed by VHDL-2000 (which was replaced by VHDL-2002).

Comment: hence, please remove the shared variable from your solution.

Comment: Agreed, but code is still synthesizable, just not compliant...

Comment: @po.pe  WRT you "prefer signals over variables", this problem illustrates where variables are needed, if you have to iterate over an object without time passing, then you need an object that updates immediately - hence, a variable.   The while loop is unlikely to be synthesizable and the algorithm uses more subtractions than is probably necessary.

Comment: @Jim Lewis I'm not arguing with that. I just say you often see people coming from sequential code languages and then using variables for all kind of stuff where a signal would be more appropriate but doesn't match with their understanding of code flow.

Comment: @po.pe Ah, but you also said, "But so far I newer came across a use-case where a variable was needed."  And my response was simply, here it is - this one is in the class of items that make sense.